# Node.js web server

Tags: node.js

I would like to access `http://mypublicIP:2888` with Node.js running on `mypublicIP` and `port`.  The server times out!  Does anyone know why this is happening?  What can I try to do to identify the underlying problem?

**EDIT**

I believe if you don't specify the IP address, Node should be reachable from all network interfaces.  Node code:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});


server.listen(2888);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running somewhere....");
```

Comment: Possible firewall issue, but there's way too little info to solve easily.

Comment: What is you code please ?

Comment: Note that your examples use port 8000, but your code uses port 2888.

Comment: Is the computer behind a router with the public IP? In that case, have you forwarded the port from the router to this computer?

Comment: How do I check whether the computer is behind a router with the public IP?

Comment: @user2939415 If the IP# as seen on the machine starts with 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x or is in the range 172.16.x.x – 172.31.x.x, you're behind a router that translates to your public IP address. In that case, you'll need to set the router up to reach your machine. If it's a home router, how to do that is probably better asked at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

on the apache machine:

- check that node is actually listening on port 8000
- check that it's reachable from localhost
- check that the request appears in apache's access_log
- check if anything relevant appears in apache's error_log

these translate to (on Linux):

```
netstat -tnlpe | grep -w 8000
telnet localhost 8000
tail /var/log/apache/access_log
tail /var/log/apache/error_log
```

Comment: Are you addressing the http://mypublicIP/node/ part?  This part IS working.  The first part is not.